# How to select unlinked <a> urls with RegExp in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a variable that stores html code for a webpage. The html code may includes a set of urls, some of these urls are linked using the anchor tag  but other may not linked using the tag.

How can I select the unlinked urls to replace them with a linked version.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
magna https://www.google.com aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
Duis aute <a href="https://www.google.com">google.com</a>
irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse

<a href="https://www.google.com">google.com</a>
https://www.google.com
```

Comment: Some code would be helpful

Comment: i think its "required" not just helpful

Comment: Please do read the tag descriptions before adding them to a question. The [tag:qregularexpression] tag has nothing to do with JavaScript regular expressions.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan sorry for that